# Why operator method for differential equation gives wrong result?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm confused with the result of operator method for equation: 
$$y''-a^2y=b,$$
 where b is a constant. Right answer is:
$$ y(t) = y(0)\cosh(at)+y'(0)\sinh(at)-\dfrac b {a^2}.$$
 But when I apply Laplace transform I've got: 
$$p^2Y-py(0)-y'(0)-a^2Y=\dfrac bp ... \\
y(t)=(y(0)+b/a^2)\cosh(at)+(y'(0)/a)\sinh(at)-\frac b {a^2}.$$
 So here a strange member $\dfrac b {a^2}\cosh(at)$ appears. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Your "right answer" is wrong.  Just set $t=0$.  You'll get $$y(0) = y(0) - \frac{b}{a^2}$$ which is nonsense for $b\neq 0$

Answer (score 2):

$$p^2Y-py(0)-y'(0)-a^2Y=b/p $$
$$Y(p^2-a^2)=py(0)+y'(0)+ \frac b p $$
$$Y=\dfrac p {(p^2-a^2)}y(0)+\dfrac {y'(0)}{(p^2-a^2)}+ \frac b {{(p^2-a^2)}p} $$
You have to decompose the last fraction:
$$\frac b {{(p^2-a^2)}p}=\frac {bp}{a^2} \left (\frac 1{p^2-a^2}-\frac 1 {p^2} \right )$$
$$\boxed {y(t)=(y(0)+\frac {b}{a^2}  )\cosh(at)+\dfrac {y'(0)}a\sinh(at)-\frac {b}{a^2}}$$

You can also write the solution as:
$$y(t)=c_1\cosh(at)+c_2\sinh(at)-\frac {b}{a^2}$$
Or also;
$$y(t)=c_1e^{at}+c_2e^{-at}-\frac {b}{a^2}$$
All these formulations are coorect.

Comment: @BrianMoehring You 're right. So I edited my answer. Thanks Brian.